# Setting cookie to control content using PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I am using a cookie to display a privacy alert at the top of a web page and for some reason is only works on the second click of the button and not the first.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

The cookie is set to 10 seconds for testing.

Thanks,

John

```
    <?php

       echo "Cookie: ".$_COOKIE['privacy_warning'];

       if (isset($_POST['privacy_button'])) {

       setcookie('privacy_warning', true,  time()+10); // 10 seconds

       }

       if (!isset($_COOKIE['privacy_warning'])):

?>

    <p class="text-center alt">We use cookies to make interactions with our websites and services easy and meaningful, to better understand how they are used and to tailor advertising. You can read more and make your cookie choices <a href="../privacy/" style="color:white;"><u>here</u></a>. By continuing to use this site you are giving us your consent to do this.<br></p>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" >
       <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center large-12 columns">
             <button class="button tiny success" type="submit" name="privacy_button">ACCEPT</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>

    <?php

       endif;

    ?>
```

Comment: _“Can anyone see why this is happening?”_ - anyone who actually read the manual for setcookie carefully perhaps? It explicitly says there in a section titled _Common Pitfalls_, _“Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires.”_

Comment: @Cbroe - thanks for the comment. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is not an issue, it's the way cookies work.

> Cookies are set using the Set-Cookie HTTP header, sent in an HTTP
>   response from the web server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation

Let's say you call the index.php and set a cookie in there, why isn't it available in the same PHP script? Since the server is sending the header and body at once, so there is no "hey, send this cookie header first and then do other stuff". The cookie is received by the client when the PHP script has ended and sent it's header + body.

To solve your issue, you could do it like that:

```
        <?php

       echo "Cookie: ".$_COOKIE['privacy_warning'];

       $privacy_warning = false;

       if (isset($_POST['privacy_button'])) {

       setcookie('privacy_warning', true,  time()+10); // 10 seconds
       $privacy_warning = true;

       }

       if (!privacy_warning):

?>

    <p class="text-center alt">We use cookies to make interactions with our websites and services easy and meaningful, to better understand how they are used and to tailor advertising. You can read more and make your cookie choices <a href="../privacy/" style="color:white;"><u>here</u></a>. By continuing to use this site you are giving us your consent to do this.<br></p>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" >
       <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center large-12 columns">
             <button class="button tiny success" type="submit" name="privacy_button">ACCEPT</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </form>

    <?php

       endif;

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

your code was ok
i run below code and it was worked fine :

```html
<?php

echo "Cookie: ".$_COOKIE['privacy_warning'] . " done \n";
setcookie('privacy_warning', 'ohuuuum',  time()+10);


if (!isset($_COOKIE['privacy_warning'])):

    ?>

    <p class="text-center alt">We use cookies to make interactions with our websites and services easy and meaningful, to better understand how they are used and to tailor advertising. You can read more and make your cookie choices <a href="../privacy/" style="color:white;"><u>here</u></a>. By continuing to use this site you are giving us your consent to do this.<br></p>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center large-12 columns">
                <button class="button tiny success" type="submit" name="privacy_button">ACCEPT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<?php

endif;

?>
```

i ran this code when it run my cookie is set to "ohuuuum" and when i reload the page the result was ===> Cookie: ohuuuum done

Comment: Yeah but you did reload the page and that's not the functionality he asked for.